# Hourly data in DataFrame with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I have a DataFrame that is based on a DateTimeIndex.  I only want the hourly data and it is every 5 minutes unless there are some drop outs in the data.  I think what I need to use is df.resample('1H'), but this automatically does df.resample('1H').mean().  I just want the hourly samples exactly the way they are.  Does anyone know to to achieve this?

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: I think `df.resample('H').asfreq()`. Your question is very unclear though. Show a representative sample of your dataframe and your desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `last`

```
df.resample('1H').last()
```

And as PaulH eluded to

```
df.asfreq('H')
```

Should also work

Comment: df.resample('1H').last() did not work, but as long as it was on the hour (exactly 8:00 or 9:00, etc)  df.asfreq('H') worked for me.